# Route Model binding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-models

I have a Laravel app and a model `Category`. It has a relation to itself called `parent`

`Category.php`

```
public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

I'm trying to make this kind of URL,

ex.: `domain.com/mobile-phones/smartphones`
('mobile-phones' - category's parent, 'smartphones' - category itself)

In the routes file it should be:

```
Route::get('/{parent}/{category}', ...)->name('category');
```

Is there a way to code so i use just one Route Parameter?
For example:

```
Route::get('/{category:parent}/{category}', ...)->name('category');
```

Also a way so that in blade files when i generate the url to use just the category.

```
route('category', ['parent' => $category->parent, 'category' => $category]); // No
route('category', $category); // Yes
```

I have tried making the route binding as follows:

```
/{category:parent}/{category}
```

But it gives the error that the parameter `category` can be used just once.

Comment: I would expect that `Route::get('/{parent}/{category}', ...)->name('category');` would work with `route('category', ['parent' => $category->parent_id, 'category' => $category->id])`. Your Controller method would then be something like `public function category(Category $parent, Category $category) { ... }`.

Comment: No, I don't believe the routing is possible the way you want it. `Route::get('/{parent}/{category}', ...)->name('category');` is the usual and accepted way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I would define the route like this

```
Route::get('/categories/{parent}/{category}')->name('category');
```

Because it is easy to read

and on blade run a loop on the devices and just prepare the anchor tag for the route.

```
@foreach ($smartPhone as $phones)
    <a href="/categories/{{ $smartPhone->parent->name }}/{{ $smartPhone->categories }}">
      Categories
    </a>
@endforeach
```

or if wanna display the category names

```
@foreach ($smartPhone as $phones)
    <a href="/categories/{{ $smartPhone->parent->name }}/{{ $smartPhone->categories }}">
      {{ $smartPhone->category }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That's a little better, but this still won't work. Your `@foreach()` doesn't make a lot of sense when you're then referencing it as `{{ $smartPhone->parent->name }}`. `$smartPhone` is the outer variable (a Collection, Array, etc.), and this would likely throw an error. `$phone->parent->name` _might_ work, but what is `$smartPhone`? That is not in the original question, so you're kinda making up code here and hoping it answers the question. Please test your code locally and post an answer that actually works.